# Fluxion tool - ./fluxion: Permission denied

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux 2016.2 amd64 and trying to run Fluxion.

1st step: in Terminal type: `git clone https://github.com/deltaxflux/fluxion.git`

2nd step:

```
ls
cd fluxion 
ls
./fluxion
```

[image]

What causes this problem?

Comment: Please run `ls -la` on that directory, what is the interpreter? Is this a script or a binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script has no execute permission as I can see from its white colour. Give it execute permission, then run it:

```
cd ~/fluxion          #if not there already
chmod u+x fluxion
./fluxion
```